# problems with finding a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given is :
$\mathbb{R^\mathbb{R}_f}:=\{ \alpha:\mathbb{R}  \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}| \alpha(x)=0, \},
\alpha(x)\ne0$ only at finitely many points.Show that:
$\mathbb{R^\mathbb{R}_f}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^\mathbb{R}_\mathbb{R}}$ and name one of its bases.

So, showing that it is a subspace is not a big deal: just going through the conditions of a subspace.

But what about the base? Is it an infinite one?
Thank you

Comment: There is a basis that is very similar to the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (You can view points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as functions $\alpha: \{1,...,n\} \to \mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Hello copper.hat, and thank you for the answer.
with $\alpha$ defined this way I would never get all the real numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ , define

$$\alpha_r(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;\;x=r\\0&,\;\;\;x\neq r\end{cases}$$

Show now that $\;\{\alpha_r\}_{r\in\Bbb R}\;$ is a basis for $\;\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}_f\;$ .

Comment: thank you DonAntonio, now it is clear!